# Низкая скорость samba

Tags: samba, debian, ubuntu

Имеется mdadm raid1 из 2х дисков, ФС - ext4, ОС - debian 6. На всём этом деле стоит samba. Из-под ubunt'ы подключил сетевой диск. Скорость копирования с debiana на ubuntu менее 1 МБита/c! Это нормально? По тому, что я успел изучить о скорости работы самбы, это совсем не нормально! Что же мне делать?)

Comment: Upd: Я подключаюсь через wi-fi роутер. Замечено, что если подключить сервер и ноутбук напрямую витухой, то скорость порядка 10 МБайт/С, что меня вполне устроит. Но в чем может быть проблема с роутером? Speedtest.net говорит о скорости порядка 15 МБит/c, что соответствует тарифу, и явно выше, чем то, что дает самба через этот самый роутер.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать покрутить параметры [Speed Samba][1]  [1]: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?